# Ubuntu on VPS, RAM use

Tags: ubuntu, vps, ram

I am thinking to get VPS server from a provider and he offers me an option to choose OS to be installed. One of options is Ubunu latest LTS.

The question is how much RAM will ubuntu use for his own processes - not counting apache, etc

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends greatly on how many packages / drivers are installed.
The default server installation will take up about 128MB of ram without running any useful services.

The minimal installation can run in 64MB without services. Be aware that it is very minimal. 
We are running Ubuntu 10.4 LTS minimal installations in EC2 instances where they take up about 60MB of ram after booting before launching services.